# Ruby: gets.chomp 1 keypress

Tags: ruby

I want to prompt a user to either press ESC or any other key. Pressing ESC will stop all further actions. Pressing ENTER (or any other key), will perform additional actions.

Pressing ENTER works fine, but **gets** waits for the user to actually press enter. Making it no very friendly.

Is there a way to continue after 1 keypress by the user?

```
puts "Press Enter to continue or ESC to quit..."
decision = gets.chomp

if decision != "^["
    then puts "do this stuff"
else
    puts "bye"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you hardly understand what you are doing. First of all, it depends on OS you are using. I am aware of no one “standard” mechanism to be applicable to all operating systems.

Secondary, comparison against string, containing two characters, `'^'` and `'['` is by no means the same as the check against <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

The last, but not the least: `gets` is buffering an input unless <kbd>⏎</kbd> is pressed. What you need to read one char is [`IO#getc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-getc).

Here is working code for unix console:

```
puts "Press Enter to continue or ESC to quit..."
begin
  system("stty raw -echo")
  decision = STDIN.getc
ensure
  system("stty -raw echo")
end

if decision.ord != 27
  puts "do this stuff"
else
  puts "bye"
end
```

Comment: you're right. Still learning. Thanks for elaborating your reasoning, it helps a lot to know the "why".